# can cxf and axis coexist in same war

Tags: cxf, axis

Our project has axis and now we need to add some new web service, with json coming from a html client. My question is can I implement the new web service using cxf and keep the old axis web service. Or do we have to migrate all axis to cxf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely have problems.   CXF requires newer versions of wsdl4j, xmlschema, wss4j, neethi,  etc... that may or may not work with the older Axis runtime.  Some like wsdl4j may work fine.  The others are likely hugely problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem can be resolved by deploying multiple war all pointing to the same domain. Different war will have different web service. So there won't be any conflict on version of jars.